# Is the dot product in a neuron in a neural network normalized?

Tags: neural-networks

A neuron in a NN is typically defined as:

$$y = f \left ( w \cdot x + b \right )$$

If I have 100 weights (such as $w = [1,1,..., 1]$) and 100 inputs (such as $x = [1,1,...1]$), is the maximum value of my dot-product, $w \cdot x$, 100 or 1?

That is, are my inputs and weights normalized?

Comment: Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they’re not normalized. The output would be 100. You know that this is not normalized because none of the notation you’ve written for the dot product includes a normalization step.

The fact that the outputs are not normalize has lead to the development of batch norm and its relatives.

Comment: Is it common for batch norms to be used these days? Any idea how common? For example do like typical MLP's that do simple image recognition do batch norms? How about deep learning, etc.

Comment: That’s a perfectly valid question to ask, but in its own thread. But before you ask a new question, I would recommend reading the “Attention is All You Need” paper and then noting how many citations it has. If you do this, you’ll be able to answer the question yourself.